# Qs regarding query time filtering

Tags: azure-cognitive-search

Regarding query time filter results returned by Azure Search - At a high level, are the documents scored before the filter is applied or after? As per the online docs, we interpreted that the docs are first filtered and then scored. Is that correct? My thinking is that filters can be useful for caching and that caching should be used without storing any scores.

Answer (score 0):

The mechanics of search execution in Azure Search are documented in good detail here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/search/search-lucene-query-architecture

Conceptually you can think of filters being executed before search and the matching documents then scored, even though in practice the process is not as distinctly separated. This indeed makes the different parts of the filter expression good candidates for caching.